# blank field in a column is not showing

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table destination whose column are id, name, region, pic. I have some rows where pic column have no values but it did not showing empty, I mean when i applied a query:

```
select * from destination where pic= ''
```

or

```
select * from destination where pic is null
```

It did not any result .whats the matter, anyone have some idea???

Comment: what is the data type of pic column

Comment: What looks like "no value" is neither `NULL` nor an empty string.

Comment: I have removed the `jquery` tag which is irrelevant to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely white characters. Use `hex(pic)` to verify

Answer (score 0):

If it is white chars, You could try this:

```
select * 
from destination
where ltrim(rtrim(pic)) = ''
```

Comment: (1) This will work only for SPACE (HEX= 20) (2) There is no point using both ltrim and rtrim in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`select * from destination where pic like ' '`
OR

`select * from destination where pic=char(32)`

Comment: may be its not blank or null ,just a space

Comment: Second query will definitely work,even though there are multiple spaces

Answer (score 0):

By no values you mean you don't see anything, but if they are not NULL and not '' then they must be having some values, white spaces most likely.

Assuming the field is a text field you can:

```
SELECT LENGTH(fieldName) FROM tableName ORDER BY LENGTH(fieldName)
```

This will show a table of 1 column indicating the length of the string inside the fieldName. It also sorts the result according to this length, so if there is any record with an empty string it would indicate 0. If no result with 0 value shows up, then they must be having white spaces.

In this case, you can compare the values like this.

```
SELECT * FROm tableName WHERE TRIM(fieldName) = '' OR fieldName Is NULL
```

Comment: I know, I still think you should keep that for future cases. If the DB is alive, new data may come in and I should not assume it will always behave the same way. That SQL should work for all cases.